# attach file from DAM to send mail in cq/AEM

Tags: aem, email-attachments

i was trying to send a mail from cq-DAM but failed.

i can send files from my own pc, i want to get the files from DAM

here is the code ::

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String key = parameterNames.nextElement();
        parameters.put(key, request.getParameter(key));

    }
    Resource templateRsrc = request.getResourceResolver().getResource("/etc/notification/send-email.html");
    String mailId = request.getParameter("mailId");
    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath("/media/intelligrape/MyFiles/Xtra/Crafting/Paper Work/images.jpg");
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    attachment.setDescription("Picture of John");
    attachment.setName("John");

    int code = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    try {
        final MailTemplate mailTemplate = MailTemplate.create(templateRsrc.getPath(), templateRsrc.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class));
        final HtmlEmail email = mailTemplate.getEmail(StrLookup.mapLookup(parameters), HtmlEmail.class);
        logger.error("PROPERTIES****************************     "+parameters);
        email.addTo(mailId);
        email.attach(attachment);

        URL url = new URL("<any URL except localhost>");
        String cid = email.embed(url, "Apache logo");

        email.setHtmlMsg("<html><body>The ig logo - <img src=\"cid:"+cid+"\"></body></html>");

        email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");
        messageGateway = messageGatewayService.getGateway(HtmlEmail.class);
        messageGateway.send(email);
```

thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get InputStream of the DAM image and convert it to [ByteArrayDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) and then use [attach](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html#attach(javax.activation.DataSource,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))(datasource,name,description) method to attach the DAM image to email.

```
Node contentNode = imageNode.getNode("jcr:content");
Binary imageBinary = contentNode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary();
InputStream imageStream = imageBinary.getStream();
ByteArrayDataSource imageDS = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageStream,"image/jpeg");
email.attach(imageDS,"Some Image","Some Description");
```